# Direct Message Selenium Instagram

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

all trust that you're well I'm trying to inspect the textarea of the Instagram Direct Message section using selenium, however, my attempts in finding the path have been unsuccessful, would appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

```
txt_box = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea')
        txt_box.send_keys(f"Hey @{user}")  # Customize your message
```

Error I receive upon running the code:

```
 txt_box = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder="Message..."]')
Exception in thread Test 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\veron.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\veron.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\veron.000\Desktop\Eros\Instagram\Instgram Dm v1\Final\Multi_Dm.py", line 83, in test_instance
    send_msg(usrnamee)
  File "c:\Users\veron.000\Desktop\Eros\Instagram\Instgram Dm v1\Final\Multi_Dm.py", line 73, in send_msg
    txt_box.send_keys(f"Hey @{user}, I'm Jordan from ARICCI’s Talent Recruitment in London.\nWe’re an upcoming sunglasses brand and we would love to see you in our new pieces!\n\nWould you be down for promoting us and earning FREE products, BIG commissions, and getting featured on our official Instagram page?\n\n DM us @ariccirecruiter to get started! Offer runs out in 48 hours. ⏳")  # Customize your message
  File "C:\Users\veron.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 540, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\veron.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\veron.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
```

Comment: maybe element has different location and you should use `xpath` without all `div` which may change in browser when it adds new values. You should use `class` or `id` if it possible. You may also use other attributes - like `Message...` in `placeholder`

Comment: Hey @furas trust that you're well, I've tried the class `textarea` it used to work however it no longer works.

Comment: `<textarea placeholder="Message..." class="" style="height: 18px !important;"></textarea>`

Comment: maybe first you should check something simpler. Maybe first use xpath `//textarea` to get all textareas and send text to all of them.

Comment: do you get any error message when you run code? You should always show FULL error message in question (not in comments)

Comment: @furas would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: how about `//textarea[@placeholder="Message..."]` ?

Comment: you didn't show minimal working code so I will not show minimal example.

Comment: @furas my apologies, I've updated the question.

Comment: I've tried `//textarea[@placeholder="Message..."]` it exited with the same error.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: you don't get ERROR when you search textarea - it is only warning that in new version you have to use `find_element(by.XPATH,...)`. So it found textarea without problem. Your real error is when you `send_key` because your text has some chars which it can't send. Maybe try without emoji

Comment: @furas it worked sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full error message shows that there is no problem with finding `textarea`.
There is only `warning` that in next version you will have to use `find_element(By.XPATH)`.

The real problem makes `send_key()`. It seems it has problem to send some chars.
Probabaly it has problem to send `emoji` - so try without `emoji`.